# Drop down vs list for nonprofit site

Tags: html, list

I need to edit this for a nonprofit site:

```
<form id="evtform" name="evtform" action="TR">
<input name="pg" type="hidden" value="entry" />
<select id="trSelectList" name="fr_id">
</select>
<input id="databtn" name="databtn" type="submit" value="Go to Event" />
</form>
```

to display a list of links to events rather than a drop down.

Comment: Just wrap the elements inside `<ul><li>Content here</li></ul>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="trSelectList" name="fr_id"></select>
```

this is the html to render a drop down.

since you do not need a dropdown simply remove this section and add

```
<a href='link'>click</a>
```

for each link you need.
this will give a link on 'click'. clicking on it will redirect to 'link'

Comment: Since the events are being pulled into the dropdown currently, is there a way to pull this into a list without creating an individual link for each event? i.e. events will be added/removed as they are created/deleted without adding in '<a href='link'>click</a>' for each one?

Comment: if you want a link so that clicking it will take you to some other page then you need <a>. Can you explain what is the use case.

Comment: We are currently using a drop down list on the organization website for participants to choose an event, but they'd prefer to have a list of events and want it to populate based on active events.